# Параметры и контейнер SSL сертификата для WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, https, windows-service

Добрый день!

Постараюсь коротко описать суть вопроса. Есть три сервера заказчиков, на каждый ставится служба написанная на C# с использованием WCF (хотя не думаю что это сильно важно).
 Заказчик должен подготовить SSL сертификаты и установить их на сервера.
Служба успешно работает с самозаверенным сертификатом.

От заказчика пришло письмо с вопросом со следующим текстом: 
**"Какие параметры должны быть у сертификата, в каком контейнере их нужно размещать? Может ли это быть один сертификат с несколькими SNI?"**

1. Вообще на сколько я понимаю они нам просто должны выдать имя хоста и порт для настройки службы, а как уж там они установят сертификаты нас мало должно волновать?
2. Насчет SNI я думаю что вообще возможно сделать и один сертификат с тремя SNI, но надежней будет если это будет три сетификата. Верно ли это?
3. Важны ли для меня параметры сертификата?
4. Спрашивают про контейнер. Возможно я неправильно понимаю, это виды файлов в которых должен быть сертификат? По идее мне он не важен, т.к. я не работаю с самими фалами.

Я не спец по безопасности и боюсь, что быстро подготовить ответ на вопрос заказчика не получится, да и по договору они должны самостоятельно всё подготовить, без нашего участия. Но в то же время не хочется чтобы подготовленная нами служба не запустилась из-за сертификатов.

Answer (score 1):

Видно, что специалисты с обеих сторон (и вы и заказчик) имеют слабое понимание о SSL-сертификатах, вопрос в общем-то про них и имеет малое отношение к WCF.

Если отвечать вкратце.

Контейнеры. Есть три вида контейнеров:

[image: хранилища сертификатов]

Если служба является службой Windows, службой, выполняющейся в режиме сервера без какого-либо пользовательского интерфейса от имени учетной записи сетевой службы, используйте хранилище локального компьютера.

Далее. С параметрами сертификата напутать что-то крайне сложно. Тут два варианта: либо покупают сертификаты для каждого хоста у коммерческой конторы типа Thatwe (для сайта subdomain1.mycompany.ru, subdomain2.mycompany.ru и subdomain3.mycompany.ru), либо используют собственный УЦ (Active Directory, server1.mydomain, server2.mydomain и server3.mydomain).

И в том и в другом случае очень сложно подобрать такие параметры сертификата, чтобы WCF "не взлетел". Просите "пачку обычного порошка", обычный сертификат (для официальных ответов между организациями: "к параметрам сертификата не предъявляется особых требований"). Главное - пусть проверят всю цепочку доверия до корневых сертификатов.

Про SNI. Тут кто-то плохо понимает технологию. Гуглите и просвещайтесь. SNI нужен, когда на одном и том же IP нужно развернуть три разных сайта. Вы же сказали "три сервера" (читай как "три разных IP-адреса"), SNI не играет никакой роли. Поэтому можете ответить "без разницы" или "да, может - но это совершенно необязательно, пока вы не будете хостить все N инстансов на одной машине". И даже в случае одного сервера можно как использовать N сертификатов, так и поставить один с несколькими SNI.

И последнее. Вам не всё ли равно, какие пропишут URL для сервиса? Вынесите настройки endpoint'ов в app.config и пусть как хотят, так и настраивают каждый инстанс. Пропишут `<endpoint address="https://msk-srv-01.mycompany.tld:8084/url` и пусть сами готовят сертификат для этого адреса (в конфигах параметры сертификата не задаются).